# Did Thomas Edison say "There is no substitute for hard work"?

Tags: quotes, thomas-edison

The quote "There is no substitute for hard work" is widely attributed to Thomas Edison, however, is anyone able to locate an original source of the quote?

Comment: Can you point to a reference which attributes this quote to Edison? While I've heard the quote, I don't specifically recall it being attributed to him.

Comment: @Jamiec  http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/t/thomasaed131293.html

Comment: related meta: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/should-we-limit-quote-questions/3194#3194

Comment: I have heard other similar quotes attributed to Edison, though I don't recall that one.  He is widely [credited with](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/genius-is-one-percent-perspiration-ninety-nine-percent-perspiration.html) "Genius is one percent inspiration, ninety-nine percent perspiration".

Comment: And I would point out that "There is no substitute for hard work" is such a straight-forward and, dare I say, "obvious" sentiment that it was likely invented (in some other language) about 2000 BC.  It seems pointless to search for an "origin".

Answer (score 5):

The earliest attribution to Edison I see is in the 1925 [New Yorker](https://books.google.com/books?id=Wq0eAQAAMAAJ&q=%22new%20yorker%22%20%22Thomas%20A.%20Edison%20once%20said,%20There%20is%20no%20substitute%20for%20hard%20work.%22&dq=%22new%20yorker%22%20%22Thomas%20A.%20Edison%20once%20said,%20There%20is%20no%20substitute%20for%20hard%20work.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrq42m3M7cAhVEiFkKHRx8AzgQ6AEIJzAA):

> Thomas A. Edison once said, “There is no substitute for hard work.”

However earlier references make clear that it was [James J. Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_J._Hill).

For example, in the article [Handling Men For the Big Results](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rl0kAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA307&dq=%22no%20substitute%20for%20hard%20work%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJz6Hr3M7cAhXDk1kKHUMIBAcQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=%22no%20substitute%20for%20hard%20work%22&f=false) *System* March 1908 it is stated:

> "There's no substitute for hard work in business," says James J. Hill

And earlier, in the article [J. J. Hill to Young Men](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn87096037/1901-09-26/ed-1/seq-4/#date1=1789&index=12&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=hard+substitute+work&proxdistance=5&date2=1925&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=no+substitute+for+hard+work&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) *The Hope Pioneer* 26 September 1901:

> There is no substitute for hard work in winning success

There is a more detailed account in [James J. Hill's Rules](https://books.google.com/books?id=dUZOAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA281&dq=%22no%20substitute%20for%20hard%20work%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivq8TK2s7cAhWpxVkKHSJlDcwQ6AEITzAG#v=onepage&q=%22no%20substitute%20for%20hard%20work%22&f=false) *The World's Work* January 1917:

> a letter which he wrote in 1882 to Mr. Stephens which says "...There is no substitute for hard work, and the value of a railway is its capacity to earn money"

But even Hill was probably not the first to say this.  The 5 October 1880 *Memphis Daily Appeal* printed an [address of Dr. Julius Wise to students of the Memphis Hospital Medical College](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045160/1880-10-05/ed-1/seq-4/#date1=1789&index=7&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=hard+substitute+Work&proxdistance=5&date2=1925&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=no+substitute+for+hard+work&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2):

> Bear in mind gentlemen, that there is no substitute for hard work